# Matlab problem with writing equations

Tags: matlab

i am having problem with writing equations.

r = 25, k= 2, R = 50:25:600, DR = 0.5:0.5:4.0

h= r*[1-cos(asin((sqrt(2*R*DR+DR^2))+r*sin(acos(r-k)/r)/r))]-k

but as a resault i get this: h = 1.9118e+001 +1.7545e+002i.

I just start with Matlab. Thanks

Comment: when i used calculator, as a result i got 4,56

Answer (score 2):

What I get from what you've written is actually

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

which is correct because you're trying to multiply two row vectors by one another. Could you please show us the actual code you used?

Anyway, supposing that's dealt with somehow, it looks to me as if you're feeding something to `asin` that's much bigger than 1. That'll give you complex results. Is the thing you're passing to `asin` perhaps meant to be divided by `R^2` or `DR^2` or something of the kind? You have a similar issue a bit later with the argument to `acos`.

I also suspect that some of your `*` and `^` and `/` operators should actually be elementwise ones `.*`, `.^`, `./`.

Comment: Well, maybe my question is a little confusing. As a result i need to get a table( or matrix), so in first equation i used R= 50, DR = 0.5, r= 25, k=2 and i need to get h. In second equation i used R=75, DR=1.0, r=25, k=2...for a last equation i used R=600,DR=4.0,r=25,k=2.

Comment: Same thing for `acos(r-k)`, maybe you mean `acos((r-k)/r)`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: formula adjusted slightly (bracketing) to reflect success in comment.

When you say you want a table, I guess it is to be an `R` by `DR` table (since you have to vectors of different length). To do that you need to use `R` as a column vector (`R'` below) and multiply with `*` (not `.*`). When `R` doesn't appear in a term multiply by `ones(size(R))` (or use `repmat`) to get DR into the right shape. To square `DR` by element, you need `DR.^2`. There seems to be a misplaced bracket for the `acos`, surely you divide by `r` before taking the `acos`. There must be a division by something like `r` in the `asin` (not `r^2` because you've taken the `sqrt`). Finally, the last division by `r` is redundant as written, since you multiply by `r` at the same level just before. Anyway, if I do the following:

```
h= r*(1-cos(asin((sqrt(2*R'*DR+ones(size(R))'*DR.^2)/r)+sin(acos((r-k)/r)))))-k
```

I get an `R` by `DR` table. Results for small `R,DR` are real; higher `R,DR` are complex due to the argument of the first `asin` being >1. The first entry in the table is 4.56, as you require.

Comment: thanks, I listened to your advice, and computer piece by piece, so I finally got the right formula. I just took r = 25, k = 2, R = 50, DR = 0.5, and included in this formula h= r*[1-cos(asin((sqrt(2*R*DR+DR.^2)/r)+(r*sin(acos((r-k)/r))/r)))]-k, and as a result got a 4.56.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do as you said:

> so in first equation i used  R= 50, DR
>   = 0.5, r= 25, k=2 and i need to get h. In second equation i used  R=75,
>   DR=1.0, r=25, k=2...for a last
>   equation i used 
>   R=600,DR=4.0,r=25,k=2.

DR and R need to be the same length... so if R goes between 50 and 600 in increments of 25, DR should go from 0.5 to ***12.5*** in increments of 0.5, or 0.5 to 4.0 in increments of ***0.1522***...

once you figure that out, be sure the add a period before every matrix multiplication operation (e.g. * or ^)